# Expressing "getting stuck with something" in German

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, english-to-german

I am trying to figure out the proper way of expressing "getting stuck with something" in German.

Let me give some example sentences:

1. > We need to register for classes early, or else we will get stuck with the old, musty professor.
2. > There were so many people at the party, I got stuck with the seat in the corner.
3. > I got stuck with working on a project that I do not enjoy.

I have come across, "auf etwas sitzen bleiben", and "feststecken", but they seem to describe different things, and I am not sure where the demarcation is.

Let me try to translate the above sentences:

1. > Wir müssen uns früh anmelden, sonst werden wir mit dem alten, muffigen Lehrer sitzen bleiben(?)
2. > Es war so viele Leute auf der Party, ich …

   (I will not try to mix "Sitz" with "sitzen bleiben" here, I know it will sound funny … or will it?)
3. > Ich musste auf ein Projekt sitzen bleiben, das mir nicht so recht gefällt.

Comment: Just a side note: „auf etwas sitzen bleiben“ typically refers to not getting to sell a product one was hired to produce/procure etc. Let’s say a painter was hired to paint miss Pamblechuke, but she didn’t buy the painting, because her nose appeared too big. He could say: „Ich habe so viel Geld für das Material ausgegeben und nun bleibe ich auf dem Bild sitzen!“

Answer (score 10):

> mit etwas vorliebnehmen müssen

helps here. In your first two examples it means having to accept an outcome, that would not have been your first choice.

> Wir müssen uns frühzeitig anmelden, sonst werden wir mit dem alten verstaubten Professor vorliebnehmen müssen.
>
> Es waren so viele Leute bei der Feier, dass ich mit dem Platz in der Ecke vorliebnehmen musste.

For your last example

> mit etwas feststecken/festhängen

might work:

> Ich hänge in einem Projekt fest, das ich nicht mag.

Comment: *mit etwas vorliebnehmen müssen* ist allerdings eine ziemlich manieristische Ausdrucksweise. In einem alten Theaterstück könnte das vorkommen. Im Alltag heutzutage redet man so kaum. Oder wenn, dann vielleicht ironisch.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @lejonet's answer. In

> auf etwas sitzen bleiben

the "auf" is important. In your example you switched it to "mit" (mit dem alten, muffigen Lehrer sitzen bleiben). This doesn't work in this case. "Auf etwas sitzen bleiben" referes to something you want to get rid of and you can't. A very good example is, if you have a shop, ordered a product and it just doesn't sell.

> feststecken

has a more literal meaning. Either a person or a thing is really stuck in the sense of not being able to move or to be moved. Or it is very close to that meaning, like being stuck in traffic in the sense of a location.

Answer (score 1):

Well-formed sentences that could occur in practice are:

Uninspiring teacher:

> Wir müssen uns zeitig anmelden, sonst kriegen wir den alten Muffel ab.
>
> Wir müssen uns zeitig anmelden, sonst bleiben auf dem alten Muffel da hängen.
>
> Wir müssen uns zeitig anmelden, sonst ziehen wir die Arschkarte und kriegen den alten Muffel.

(Attention, this is pretty rude; but students often talk that way when there is no teacher in sight.)

Unattractive seat at a party:

> Es war so viele Leute auf der Party, ich hab' bloß noch einen Platz in der Ecke bekommen.
>
> Die Party war super voll. Für mich gabs nur noch Platz am Katzentisch.

("Katzentisch" is a smaller, separate table aside from the large, prestigeous table where the important people sit. Don't ask me why it is called *Katzentisch*. It is a commonly used idiom.)

Unfavourable project at work:

> Jetzt ist das Projekt, das ich überhaupt nicht mag, an mir hängengeblieben.
>
> Ich bin bei der Arbeit auf einem Projekt sitzengeblieben, das ich überhaupt nicht mag.

**Higher registers of speach**

Similar to *vorliebnehmen müssen mit* mentioned before by others (which is an unusual high register of language) there is also the expression *sich bescheiden müssen mit*. Both however do not occur in normal everyday language, unless perhaps ironically. So you can say

> Die Party war extrem gut besucht. Ich musste mit einem Platz am Katzentisch vorliebnehmen.
>
> Ich musste mich mit einem Platz am Katzentisch (einem Platz in der Ecke) bescheiden.

but this is rather formal language then. Perhaps to be found in a novel, a written report or so, but not in everyday communication.

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe go into more detail on how "hängenbleiben" is used here? You wrote, "...das Project... an mir hängengeblieben", and also, "...bleiben auf dem alten Muffel da hängen." I understand that "hängen bleiben" is used to describe objects that get stuck or caught on something, and I'm wondering if this is also a nice word for getting stuck with something undesirable, as in my example sentences. Can you tell me why you chose "AUF DEM Professor hängen bleiben" and "das Projekt ist AN MIR hängengeblieben"? or what the "method to the madness" here is :)

Comment: These are colloquial expressions. I rendered them here as I would hear them (or use them myself) in everyday situations. I am afraid they are not very open to logical explanations why they are used that way and not the other. A hypothesis may be that there are underlying scenarios. Easy for "Das Projekt ist an mir hängengeblieben": imagine a piece of dirt spinning off a wheel and stick to your jacket. For the professor: perhaps imagine a vehicle trying to get over an obstacle, e.g. again a heap of dirt, and gets stuck on top of it because the wheels lose traction? But I am making up these...

Comment: [cont. from above] ... scenarios so that they fit the wording used in my sentences. I do not know if this is a legitimate method, or if you would find it a circular explanation.